# Provider keeps on executing and data gets added to the list infinite in flutter

Tags: flutter, state, provider

I am using Provider to manage the app state in flutter and use provider to call api and store it in model class and provider is called inside build method, its an inventory app.

when cart page is opened, provider to fetch cart items is called and cart items will be displayed, but the issue is the api to fetch cart items keeps on executing infinitly, in ui data gets replicated. Can anyone please help with this issue.

the code to call cart provider is

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        User? user = _auth.currentUser;
        var phoneNumber = user!.phoneNumber;

        final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);

        cartProvider.fetchCartByUser(user.phoneNumber.toString());


        final testString = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

        return
        isEmpty
            ? Scaffold(body: CartEmpty())
            :
             Scaffold
            ( //display cart items)
```

cart provider class is

```
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    List<CartModel> _cartItems = [];

  List<CartModel> get cartItems {
    return [..._cartItems];
  }

  CollectionReference cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cart');

    Future<void> fetchCartByUser(String phoneNumber) async 
    {
          await Server.getCartData().then((value)
          {
              for(var item in value)
              {
                    _cartItems.insert
                    (
                        0,
                        CartModel
                        (
                            cartId: item['cartId'],
                            clientAddress: item['clientAddress'],
                            clientFullname: item['clientFullname'],
                            clientPhoneNumber: item['clientPhoneNumber'],
                            createdAt: item['createdAt'],
                            merchant: item['merchant'],
                            merchantCode: item['merchantCode'],
                            price: item['price'],
                            productCode: item['productCode'],
                            productImage: item['productImage'],
                            productName: item['productName'],
                            productQty: item['productQty'],
                            productSKU: item['productSKU'],
                        ),
                    );
                }
          });

        notifyListeners();
    }

  Future<void> deleteSingleCart(String cartId) async {
    await cart
        .doc(cartId)
        .delete()
        .then((value) => print("Cart Deleted"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete user: $error"));
    // this.fetchCartByUser();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> updateProductQty(String cartId, String qty) async {
    await cart.doc(cartId).update({'productQty': qty});
  }

  double get totalAmount {
    var total = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < _cartItems.length; i++) {
      total +=
          int.parse(_cartItems[i].price) * int.parse(cartItems[i].productQty);
    }

    return total;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to move logic of fetching data to `initState`. Because build method can be called many times, the data is being fetched many times as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
  @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();

     WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     // Here you can fetch data login
     });
  }
```